# What does a kitten want when it looks at you and meows a lot?

Tags: cats, behavior

Could it mean any number of things when my new kitten looks at me and meows a few times, or is there anything specific?

I'm just curious to know what it wants.

It has got food and water and toys.

Does that mean that it's bored?

Comment: Attention. Could be boredom, could be it wants reassurance, could be many things. Sometimes mine just want to express an opinion on their world, or seem to like the echo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bored and looking for stimulation from you. My cats do this all the time.

If it didn't have food, that would be a likely cause.

If it has toys, but the toys are more fun when you're involved, that is a likely cause.

If neither of those, then maybe it wants to be chased, play hide-and-seek, have food thrown, etc. - whatever your cat's personality prefers.